# Mysql/JDBC: Deadlock

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, locking, innodb

I have a J2EE server, currently running only one thread (the problem arises even within one single request) to save its internal model of data to MySQL/INNODB-tables.

Basic idea is to read data from flat files, do a lot of calculation and then write the result to MySQL. Read another set of flat files for the next day and repeat with step 1. As only a minor part of the rows change, I use a recordset of already written rows, compare to the current result in memory and then update/insert it correspondingly (no delete, just setting a deletedFlag).

Problem: Despite a purely sequential process I get lock timeout errors (#1204) and Innodump show record locks (though I do not know how to figure the details). To complicate things under my windows machine everything works, while the production system (where I can't install innotop) has some record locks.

To the critical code:

1. Read data and calculate (works)
2. Get Connection from Tomcat Pool and set to autocommit=false
3. Use Statement to issue "LOCK TABLES order WRITE"
4. Open Recordset (Updateable) on table order
5. For each row in Recordset --> if difference, update from in-memory-object
6. For objects not yet in the database --> Insert data
7. Commit Connection, Close Connection

The Steps 5/6 have an Commitcounter so that every 500 changes the rows are committed (to avoid having 50.000 rows uncommitted). In the first run (so w/o any locks) this takes max. 30sec / table.

As stated above right now I avoid any other interaction with the database, but it in future other processes (user requests) might read data or even write some fields. I would not mind for those processes to read either old/new data and to wait for a couple of minutes to save changes to the db (that is for a lock).

I would be happy to any recommendation to do better than that.

Summary: Complex code calculates in-memory objects which are to be synchronized with database. This sync currently seems to lock itself despite the fact that it sequentially locks, changes unlocks the tables without any exceptions thrown. But for some reason row locks seem to remain.

Kind regards

Additional information: 
Mysql: show processlist lists no active connections (all asleep or alternatively waiting for table locks on table order) while "show engine INNODB" reports a number of row locks (unfortuantely I can't understand which transaction is meant as output is quite cryptic).

Comment: Are you using plain jdbc? No code makes it harder to check. Do you commit and close the connections on every write? Are you maintaining the connection open when you don't need to?

Comment: Sorry for coming back so late. I use JDBC via the standard Tomcat Connection Pooling (configured via ressource-defs in web.xml) with DataSource.getConnection.

Comment: Do not use `LOCK TABLE` in InnoDB !

Answer (score 0):

Solved: I wrongly declared a ResultSet as updateable. The ResultSet was closed only on a "finalize()" method via Garbage Collector which was not fast enough - before I reopended the ResultSet and tried therefore to aquire a lock on an already locked table.

Yet it was odd, that innotop showed another query of mine to hang on a completely different table. Though as it works for me, I do not care about oddities:-)